# DDD Aggregate Question (.NET, EF)

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, aggregate

My domain model (simplified) contains a story, team, members, and comments. I'm at the point where I need to allow the user to write a comment about a story and I have the comment entity belonging to the story aggregate, so I have a method on Story called 'AddComment'. It seems silly here to load the aggregate to save a comment, so I was wondering if I should remove this entity from the aggregate or is there something here I'm missing? I'm sure I will run into more than one of these types of scenarios, so any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Is a comment only related to the story or is it in reality a stand alone aggregate in itself?

Comment: A comment cannot exist without a story if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marco, resist the urge to allow the technical implementation to drive a change like that to your domain model. Every time I've done that, I've later regretted it. If Comments only exist within Stories, then keep Story as the aggregate and bend the technology to match the model.

Comment: when you say bend the technology, do you mean for example, in EF, figure out how to accomplish this WITHOUT first fetching the entity?

Comment: That's probably not going to work, but with lazy loading you can at least avoid pulling in all related entities (like all of the existing comments). It may not be as efficient as say an insert directly to a comments table, but having a rich, testable model is usually worth some trade-off.

Comment: So do you prefer lazy loading vs eager loading? Does your service layer "know" which entities to eager load based on its task?

Comment: My team uses NHibernate. We started out without lazy loading by default. As the model got more complex, we had to have lazy loading to keep us from having to think about what relations were necessary for each thing the we were trying to do. We could treat our model as if it was in memory all the time, and the repository pattern makes that illusion possible.

Comment: BTW, these struggles are what has made me more interested in Event Sourcing as a basis for my domain model. If you want to take the red pill on that, you can start at http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/cqrs-and-event-sourcing-synergy/.

Answer (score 1):

If the comment cannot exist without a story then why does it seem silly to load the story to save a comment? And you are not actually saving the comment, you are adding it to a story, and then you save the story.

Usually when you find yourself having these filings that you do unnecessary stuff to perform an operation it is an indication that your domain model might need more refinement. Go over all your consistency boundaries requirements ( Aggregates ), review each bounded context in your model and maybe things you missed on the first pass will surface.

As Eric Evans sais, DDD is an iterative process. You will fail the first few times :)

Comment: It will not be a wasted hour if you watch [this video](http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/evans_2009_1)